# Are nearby points in an algebraic curve necessarily connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, computational-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

I would like a result of the following form:

> For every algebraic curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{P}^{n-1}$, there exists an
>   explicit and easy-to-compute $\epsilon=\epsilon(C)>0$ such that points $x,y\in C$ satisfying $\mathrm{dist}(x,y)<\epsilon$ necessarily reside in a
>   common connected component of $C$.

For example, $\epsilon$ might be a function of the "complexity" of the polynomials that define $C$ (e.g., degrees, size of coefficients, etc.). Is such a result available in the current literature?

Comment: What about the curve $x^2y^2 - 1 = 0$? This curve has points arbitrarily close together on disconnected components.

Comment: Assuming that the above does indeed provide a counterexample to your bound, I think you could still hope for a bound of the form: `For every $C$ and radius $r$, there is an $\epsilon(C,r)$ such that if $\norm{x-y} < \epsilon$ and $\norm{x} < r$, then $x$ and $y$ reside in a common connected component.` That is, that the intersection of $C$ with some compact region $B_r$ would have the properties you want.

Comment: @Alex - Good point! My intended application has a natural interpretation in projective space, so I edited my question accordingly. By compactness, this should avoid such a counterexample.

Comment: $\epsilon$ won't be determined by the degrees alone. For example in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3$ take two skew lines. They are defined by some equations of degree $2$. But the skew lines can be as close together as you like, without changing the defining degrees. The distance $\epsilon$ should depend on the size of the coefficients of the defining polynomials.

Comment: Another question is: is there an explicit and easy way to compute the connected components $C_1,C_2,...$ of a curve?

One strategy could be: for each connected component $C_i$ find a polynomial $g_i$ with $g_i(x)\ge 1$ if $x\in C_i$ and $g_i(x)\le-1$ if $x\in C_j$, $j\neq i$. Then look at the $g_i$.

However, this approach does not sound "explicit and easy".

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithm you could reduce your problem to an optimization problem on the square $C^2$ of your curve $C$; there is a vast literature on the subject of optimization in real algebraic geometry. The distance function-squared $\mathrm{dist}^2$ is a polynomial function on the real algebraic surface $C^2$. One determines all non zero critical values of $\mathrm{dist}^2$ on $C^2$ and then takes $\epsilon^2$ to be equal to the minimum of those critical values. I'm not sure, however, whether that can be done very efficiently in terms of complexity.

Comment: @jarauh Here is how I would compute the connected components of $C = \{ f(x,y)=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Make a generic linear change of coordinates such that $C$ has no vertical asymtotes and such that $C$ has no vertical bitangents nor is there any vertical line tangent to a flex. Let $\Delta(x)$ be the discriminant of $f$ with respect to $y$ and let $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_N$ be the real roots of $\Delta$. (continued)

Comment: The lines $\{ x= x_j \}$ are the vertical tangents of $C$. As a vertical line sweeps across $C$ from the left of such a tangent to the right, either two points merge and disappear or vice versa. I can find out which two points collide by looking for the double root $y_j$ of $f(x_j, y)$, and can figure out whether the merging is to the left or to the right of the tangent by computing $C$ near $(x_j, y_j)$. So I can draw a combinatorial model of $C$ by drawing points splitting and merging in the same manner.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Can you think of any analogue to such a routine in higher dimensions?  It seems like following a curve in two dimensions is amenable to techniques like working with a single polynomial (eg the discriminant) or Sturm's theorem.  What about the codimension > 1 case?

Comment: @aorq Conceptually, the same idea of taking the linear projection to a line and computing the fibers where points split and merge make sense. If the curve is a complete intersection, then we should be able to mimic this ideal using multivariate discriminants and routines for numerically computing zero-dimensional complete intersections. Non-complete intersections raise tricky issues of numerical stability, so I would want to know more about how the curve was presented first. (I'm also not an expert. The first person I would e-mail in this situation is Frank Sottile.)

Comment: An example of the stability issue: Let $F = ( f_{ij}(x,y,z) )$ be a 2 by 3 matrix of polynomials. The locus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $F$ drops to rank $1$ will generically be a smooth curve $C$. Let $F_{ab} = f_{1a} f_{2b} - f_{1b} f_{2a}$. Then $C = \{ F_{12} = F_{13} = F_{23} =0 \}$. If we numerically set all three minors $F_{ab}$ to $0$, the situation is unstable and we will only find finitely many roots. If we just set $F_{12} = F_{13}=0$, then we get both $C$ and an extra component $f_{11} = f_{21}=0$. So I'm not sure how to best study the topology of an example like this.